# What options are there for a slow hardware watchdog monitoring an embedded HTTP client?

Tags: watchdog

I'm trying to build a server health monitoring device around an ESP8266 module. The module will contain an embedded HTTP client that will contact a set of servers to check their responsiveness. The servers will answer yeh or neh essentially, and if not, the module will raise an alarm.

In order to bolster robustness, I had thought of adding an external hardware watchdog chip (like [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/c579/0900766b8134141b.pdf)). So the external watchdog chip will monitor the main ESP8266 module. Many of them have maximum timeouts of ~1.6 seconds. That's not a huge amount of time for a HTTP request to be prepared and returned if the target servers are busy. Further, the target servers will have to contact upstream peripherals to verify them too, adding more response delay. And I think that HTTP client libraries like `ESP8266HTTPClient` are synchronous/blocking.

So do I just put up with occasional resets, or is there some other way to extend the timeout period to say 5 - 10 seconds?

---

Some options that came to mind:-

1. Write a non-blocking HTTP client (not sure I can).
2. Build an NE555 timer based watchdog with 10 second delay. Debugging issues.
3. Utilise a second ucontroller as the external watchdog. Silly?
4. Don't bother with an external watchdog circuit. It's not life critical.

Comment: Surely the hardware watchdog just has to verify that the ESP module is running - not that the HTTP is working. The ESP code shouldn't be stuck in a loop waiting for the HTTP response. The watchdog could be set at 100 ms.

Comment: @Transistor   But if the ESP module is in the middle of a HTTP request (waiting for a response that might take seconds) it's effectively blocked from further processing. Therefore it can't I/O 'kick' the watchdog (at 10 Hz). It would be constantly resetting...

Comment: If it's blocked from further processing then surely your code is wrong? Any real system would have to handle button press and other events while waiting for the HTTP response. Consider how you would do two or more HTTP checks simultaneously.

Comment: @Transistor You're right and I don't know.  Remember though that it's a small embedded single threaded thingie.  It's not a server. But I've seen many examples as [this](https://techtutorialsx.com/2016/07/17/esp8266-http-get-requests/). Isn't code line 29 blocking?

Comment: Be suspicious anywhere you see the `delay()` function being used. It means that the device is blocked from doing anything else and I'd regard it as amateur - even though I'm in that group with regard to ESP programming. I don't know enough about the HTTPclient library to know if it can be periodically checked to see if it's ready while the micro runs the main loop.